# Cannot to uninstall "cqrlog" app

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3, with additional backports PPA to get LTS.

By mistake, from Synaptic Package Manager, I installed an app called: "cqrlog".

That app is useful (I guess) to the Ham Radio world, but... It is not my case, now.

So... I want to uninstall it, but... I cannot to do it!

I've tried the standard line commands:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge cqrlog
sudo apt auto-remove cqrlog
sudo apt autoclean
```

But... Nothing!

I just get the following error message (direct translated from the Spanish message):

```
dpkg: error when processing the package cqrlog (--remove):

Installed cqrlog package post-removal hyphen the subprocess gaves the output status 1

Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's wrong here?

Why I cannot to uninstall this app?

How can I uninstall that package?

Comment: You cannot uninstall the package because the post-removal script is throwing an error. If you have the skill, read the script. If you lack the skill, then use `--force`. Note that `purge` is NOT equivalent to `--force`...they do quite different things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
sudo apt remove cqrlog
```

You can also remove it from within synaptic

Comment: I couldn't remove it from Synaptic Package Manager because I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

None of the ideas the gang wrotes worked for me. So...

I decided to perform a "manual" removal of all the files with the name "cqrlog".

I did it with the files tracker called: "Catfish". At the same time, I used "Thunar", as superuser.

There were not too much files; configuration files (text) most of them.

So... I erased all of them, one by one.

Then I used the standard command line commands:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge

sudo apt autoclean
```

And... Now it seems to be uninstalled and fixed!

I don't know if this is an "Official" answer to this, but... In my case, it worked!